# Calling QCoreApplication methods from Android Activity onCreate method

Tags: android, qt, java-native-interface

I am developing a Qt-based application for Android. In case the app is launched as a result of opening a file I need to pass it to the Qt application instance. I  have created a custom Java activity so as to implement this behavior:

```java
public class MyActivity extends org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       

        Intent i = getIntent();
        String act = i.getAction();

        if (act != null) && act.compareTo(Intent.ACTION_VIEW) == 0) 
        {             
                int fd = -1;
                try
                {
                    fd = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(i.getData(), "r").detachFd();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    Log.e("MyActivity::onCreate", "Exception caught: " + e.getMessage());
                }

                boolean ok = openFd(fd);            
        }
    }   // onCreate

    private static native boolean openFd(int fd);
} // MyActivity
```

On the C++ side I have something like this:

```cpp
#include <QDebug>

#include <jni.h>

jboolean processInputFile(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint fileDescriptor)
{
    int fd = (int)fileDescriptor;

    qDebug() << "processInputFile called: " << fd;

    QFile f;
    if (f.open(fd, QIODevice::ReadOnly, QFileDevice::AutoCloseHandle))
    {
        QFileInfo fi(f);
        qDebug() << "Successfully opened the file " << f.fileName() << fi.absoluteFilePath() << fi.canonicalFilePath() << fi.fileName();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Failed to open the file: " << f.errorString();
        return false;
    }
}   // processInputFile

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void*)
{
    qDebug() << "JNI_OnLoad got called";

    JNIEnv* env;
    if (vm->GetEnv(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&env), JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK) {
        return -1;
    }

    jclass javaClass = env->FindClass("com/mycompany/mypackage/MyActivity");
    if(!javaClass)
    {
        return JNI_ERR;
    }

    // Register methods with env->RegisterNatives

    static JNINativeMethod methodsArray[] =
    {
        {"openFd", "(I)Z", (void*)processInputFile}        
    };

    if(env->RegisterNatives(javaClass, methodsArray, sizeof(methodsArray) / sizeof(methodsArray[0])) < 0)
    {
        return JNI_ERR;
    }

    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qDebug() << "Calling main()";

    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qDebug() << "main arguments:";
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        qDebug() << argv[i];

    // ...
}
```

The C++ method (processInputFile) gets invoked, but it happens **before** the main() function is called, therefore the application object has not been created yet. I can't handle the data passed in, because the processing classes do not exist at that moment. **So my question is** how can I call the methods of Qt application instance from android.app.Activity::onCreate method?

And another thing: is it possible to get the name of the file that was opened? Sometimes the intent's URI looks like "content://downloads/my_downloads/47" and neither conversion method I found worked for it. QFile and QFileInfo also do not return the name for `fd`. Knowing the name would be useful, for instance, to describe the item that is being processed, whereas 47 is not really meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution for this problem. It is a workaround but should work fine.

In the onCreate function store the filePath and the ncall it from Qt main loop:

```
public class MyActivity extends org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity
```

{
    String filePath;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       

    Intent i = getIntent();
    String act = i.getAction();
    filePath = "";

    if (act != null) && act.compareTo(Intent.ACTION_VIEW) == 0) 
    {             
            filePath = i.getData();
    }
}   // onCreate

    public String getFile()
    {
        return filePath;
    }

} // MyActivity
```

Then in your main() function in C++ call

```
QAndroidJniObject javaFilePath =  QtAndroid::androidActivity().callObjectMethod("getFile", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
QString filePath = javaFilePath.toString();
if (filePath != "") {
    // do something
}
```

I just tried it and it seems to work. It might need some more work to handle all cases but as a basic idea it seems to do the job.

Another possibility is to use pending intents as described [here](https://resources.qt.io/development-topic-mobile-apps/sharing-files-on-android-or-ios-from-or-with-your-qt-app-part-2). It also contains a solution to convert file URI to the real path.